# Visitors vs Users

Tags: discussion, statistics

How come programmers.stackexchange.com has more visitors/day than it has users?  Does the visitors count include non-registered users?

Answer (score 4):

Yes - most of Stack Overflows traffic comes from unregistered visitors via Google.

I don't have any links to hand, but Jeff has mentioned this several times.

Answer (score 4):

I would assume the vistors count does include non-registered users. I referred to SO all the time before I registered.